# How can I add distance variable to panel data?

Tags: econometrics, international-trade, international-economics

I'm working on a gravity model with a panel data. However, the distance variable for this model is a time-fixed effect so it doesn't seem possible to run the model with it.

What can I do to add this variable to the model?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think You should be able to run the following type of regression:
$$
\ln X_{i,j,t} = C + F^X_i + F^M_j + \delta_t + \alpha \ln D_{i,j}.
$$
Where $X_{i,j}$ is the trade flow from $i$ to $j$ at time $t$, $F^X_i$ and $F^M_j$ are exporter and importer fixed effects, $\delta_t$ is a time fixed effect and $D_{i,j}$ is the distance.

- You cannot add a country pair FE, $F_{i,j}$ as this will eat up the distance variable $D_{i,j}$.
- If you only have one destination $j$, you cannot add the desitnation fixed effect $F^M_j$ as this will be eaten up by the constant $C$. Also you cannot add both destination fixed effects $F^X_i$ and $D_{i,j}$ as they will be colinear.
- If you only have one origin $i$, you cannot add an origin fixed effect $F^X_i$ as it is colinear with the intercept. Also, you cannot add both $F^M_j$ and $D_{i,j}$ as these are also colinear.
- If you have only one origin and one destination, you cannot add $F^X_i$, $F^M_j$ nor $D_{i,j}$ as all of them are swallowed up by the constant term $C$.
- If you have a panel, you should, in general, have no problem adding a time fixed effect $\delta_t$.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a time invariant variable distance, then you can run a random effect model. If you use the fixed effect model the time invariant variable cannot be estimated.